# How to find out service status?

Tags: python, linux

I am executing shell commands through browser as apache user.

Is it possible to find out the service status without using service command?

Actually, Apache don't have permission to execute "service dovecot status". So please let me know other ways of finding the dovecot status.

Comment: `I am executing shell commands through browser as apache user` In my opinion, that just calls for trouble... Instead of making a backdoor to your server, you could go the other way round: You could schedule a script with crontab, that would create a HTML file indicating a status in the web content of the Apache...

Comment: Thank you..I will try with your solution